# Decrypt is rejected with message of "MetaMask DecryptMessage: User denied message decryption." even though the user clicks on "Decrypt" on Metamask

Tags: metamask, ethers.js

#### Ethers.js Version

6.5.1

#### Describe the Problem

I was trying to test the encrypt and decrypt feature of ethers.js with the public and private keys from the metamask wallet and built a really simple application that will retrieve the public key and encrypt the user's provided string, then decrypt the encrypted message to see if it will go back to the original message. When I clicked on "Decrypt" after initiating decryption, it throws the error saying the user is denying the decryption action. Screen recording attached.

The full code can be found here too: https://github.com/Eric1015/metamask-encrypt-file-example

Asked the same question here as well: https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/4139, also pending answers.

#### Code Snippet

Here is the code of how I am decrypting the message:

```
  const decryptMessage = useCallback(
    async (encryptedMessage: string) => {
      const { provider } = state;
      if (provider == null) return;
      const accounts: string[] = await provider.send('eth_requestAccounts', []);
      return await provider.send('eth_decrypt', [
        encryptedMessage,
        accounts[0],
      ]);
    },
    [state]
  );
```

The `provider` inside of the state is created in the following manner and stored as state:

```
      const { ethereum } = window;

      const provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(ethereum);
```

#### Errors

```shell
Error: user rejected action (action="unknown", reason="rejected", info={ "error": { "code": -32603, "data": { "originalError": {  } }, "message": "MetaMask DecryptMessage: User denied message decryption." }, "payload": { "id": 9, "jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "eth_decrypt", "params": [ "cynO2IeYe/weLFuV3/Ec2hhpxFFg5OU=", "<address>" ] } }, code=ACTION_REJECTED, version=6.5.1)
```

#### Environment

Ethereum (mainnet/ropsten/rinkeby/goerli)

#### Environment (Other)

Sepolia

Comment: hey @Eric did you find a solution to this?

Comment: No, on the Github side, there was a reply and he told me that this decrypt function of Metamask is gonna be deprecated, so I decided to seek for a different solution such as using the Lit protocol: https://developer.litprotocol.com/

Comment: alright, thanks for the hint regarding Lit protocol. I will take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer for this question on the Github issue side, please refer to this reply in the Github issue for details: https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/4139#issuecomment-1615971987